# Filter All Output in a Bash Session

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec

Just got the `filters` package and loving that fact that I can run, for example

```
ls | pirates
```

and have a funny (if impractical) output.

For [International Talk Like A Pirate Day](http://www.talklikeapirate.com/) I would like all my output to automatically be filtered by pirate! If I run `exec bash -i | pirate`, this works, but some strange things occur, namely not every line is finished with a new line and a new bash input character `$`

I've tried playing with redirecting stdout, and scripts but all I have tried seems to fail. Ideas?

Comment: Don't you mean `pirate` (without the `s`)? If that be true, I see no probs over herrrre

Comment: Arrr, indeed I did mean pirate, that is what I was using. Worked for you as it should? Its always newlining after output and printing the `...$` waiting for input characters? hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try exec'ing a script that pipes the shell's output to pirates:

```
cat shell.sh
bash | pirates
chmod +x shell.sh
exec ./shell.sh
```